# SQL query doesn't return the same result in SQL Server and in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I launched a query in two different environments:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- C# (.Net Core 2.2.1)

The query:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN afc.Id IS NULL 
          THEN fcv.Id 
          ELSE afc.ParentTemplateFieldContainerId 
    END AS FieldContainerId,
    fcv.TemplateFieldContainerId,
    CASE 
       WHEN fcvp.ProductId IS NULL 
          THEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
          ELSE fcvp.ProductId 
    END AS ProductId
FROM 
    FieldContainerValue fcv
LEFT JOIN
    FieldContainerValueAndProduct fcvp ON fcvp.FieldContainerValueId = fcv.Id
LEFT JOIN
    ArrayFieldContainer afc ON afc.ChildTemplateFieldContainer = fcv.Id
WHERE 
    fcv.Id IN ('337c0b2e-a83b-4014-a46a-6ce8bf9fd2c4', 'c2ca899c-28ac-4dc3-bba9-f0741bb02097')
```

The code I used to run the query in C#:

```
public IEnumerable<T> QuerySql<T> (string sql)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigMan.GetConfigProperty("ConnectionString")))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
        return conn.Query<T>(sql);
    }
}
```

`SQL` is the query.

The type that my query returns:

```
public class FieldContainerValueProperties
{
    public Guid FieldContainerValueId { get; set; }
    public Guid TemplateFieldContainerId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Results of the query: in both cases, I get the same number of items (2), but the `FieldContainerId` differs.

In SQL Server Management Studio:

```
[
    {
        "FieldContainerId": "337C0B2E-A83B-4014-A46A-6CE8BF9FD2C4",
        "TemplateFieldContainerId": "B4566675-B547-4025-ABBB-F5CC523BB092",
        "ProductId": "6E790000-FF4B-0003-C22D-08D68AB637D6"
    },
    {
        "FieldContainerId": "C2CA899C-28AC-4DC3-BBA9-F0741BB02097",
        "TemplateFieldContainerId": "591D8371-EDE8-460C-9847-3F2963D875D2",
        "ProductId": "6E790000-FF4B-0003-C22D-08D68AB637D6"
    }
]
```

From C#:

```
[
    {
        "FieldContainerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "TemplateFieldContainerId": "B4566675-B547-4025-ABBB-F5CC523BB092",
        "ProductId": "6E790000-FF4B-0003-C22D-08D68AB637D6"
    },
    {
        "FieldContainerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "TemplateFieldContainerId": "591D8371-EDE8-460C-9847-3F2963D875D2",
        "ProductId": "6E790000-FF4B-0003-C22D-08D68AB637D6"
    }
]
```

Possible explanations?

One possible explanation I can imagine is that in one case `is null` returned `true` and in the other case `false`, but I'm really not sure.

If that is indeed the case, do you know what could cause this problem ?

Comment: Run both queries (from code and SSMS) with profiler enabled. Then compare their texts and `set` options as well, some of them might affect query results.

Comment: SQL server is muti-threaded so you should always use Order By to get same results if you are taking only some of the results.  I know this isn't the case here.  In c# instead of using null use DBNULL.Value when working with a database.

Comment: Your mapping is not working. Your model class contains `FieldContainerValueId ` and your sql table `FieldContainerId` so when it maps field names are different and set value to default. Change your Model class  `FieldContainerValueId ` ->   `FieldContainerId`.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadHannan, it worked

Comment: Glad to hear, don't forget to mark my answer as resolved :) @JacquesUng

Answer (score 6):

Your mapping is not working. Your model class contains `FieldContainerValueId` and your sql table `FieldContainerId` so when it maps field names are different and set value to default. Change your Model class `FieldContainerValueId` -> `FieldContainerId`. 
New model that will work fine,

```
public class FieldContainerValueProperties
{
    public Guid FieldContainerId { get; set; }
    public Guid TemplateFieldContainerId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

**I have answered this in comments section. Writing here to just to get the post a resolved answer.